# what for .conf extension file in mac is used

Tags: macos, configuration

I found some configuration files are saved with file extension ".conf" in MAC , example httpd.conf,ldap.conf. What is the specific purpose of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Those are both UNIX configuration files. There's no common format between the two, but the .conf extension is a convention for naming them.

Comment: Thank you, But i have given them as example. My main question is to know, what is .conf naming convention is for, there might be some specific purpose

Comment: .conf = "configuration"

Comment: I know that it is for configuration, apart from that is there any specific properties for it